# Problems with images in Team Foundation Server 2010 (SP1)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We are having problems with Team Foundation Server 2010. Even after installing Service Pack 1, still sometimes **images** (in website projects) are not updated or downloaded when doing a *get latest*.

Is anyone familiar with this problem and even more important, does anyone know how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: What type of AntiVirus application are you using?  We have actually seen cases where AntiVirus is not able to handle with TFS Get commands and starts skipping some completely.

Comment: I'm not running any AntiVirus and i'm doing a Get Latest from within Visual Studio by right clicking the solution and clicking Get Latest Version (Recursive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are having the same problem in our web project we have to exclude the file from the project commit the changes and then add the image back to the project and commit it again for the image to be updated.